# is running smartctl safe?

Tags: truenas, smartctl

I cant seem to find a super easy answer for this and I am sure that RTFM applies here but I am hoping this question, asked simply, will also help many other noobs out there.

I am running freenas and getting a bunch of CAM STATUS errors and incrementing unreadable (pending) sectors. I want to run a smartctl test but I am worried about hurting the drive, and the data.

Is running a long or short smartctl test safe?

Thanks

Comment: It's just as safe as not replacing the failing drive.

Comment: so are you saying it is not safe to run smartctl?

Comment: It's not safe to keep using a drive you already know is failing. The test results won't tell you anything you don't already know.

Comment: appreciate your comment Michael. you are technically correct - which, i guess, is the best kind of correct. Regardless, i am hoping to still get an answer on the specific question. Thanks.

Comment: When you run smartctl test, you are using the drive. Using a failing drive is not safe, which means running smartctl test is not safe.

Comment: Well put Tero. If you want to make this an answer I will accept. Thanks.